# Mongo Only Return Elements of Array Matching Query

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

Given the following JSON example:

```
{
    _id: "55ef729a66d78d24008xxxx",
    name: "The right one"
    items: [{
        _id: "55ef729a66d78d24008xxxx",
        return: true
    }, {
        _id: "55ef729a66d78d24008xxxx",
        return: true
    }, {
        _id: "55ef729a66d78d24008xxxx",
        return: false
    }]
}
```

I want to write a query that specifies `items.return = true` and it should return:

```
{
    _id: "55ef729a66d78d24008xxxx",
    name: "The right one"
    items: [// 2 element array]
}
```

I've seen a lot of people suggest using $elemMatch, such as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection), but as it says, this

> only return the first match

but this just returns the parent documents that have some value in the array matching items.return. So in the above example it would return all 3 array elements.

I want to completely ignore these array values in my return. I don't want to do it in the client, because I do a project using the items _id and don't want to waste the project if I don't need it.

Comment: Different question, that question refers to returning parent documents with the exact arrays that match, I need to alter the array itself.

Comment: It's not about the question but the **answers** provided to the question. There are several answers there that use the aggregation framework to return just the matched "elements" as that is the only tool ( aside from map reduce ) that is able to do so.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative not exact you want

```
db.items.aggregate(
      {$unwind:"$items"},
      {$match:{"items.return":true}}
)
```

Answer (score 2):

One alternative is to use `$elemMatch`. Check the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/#zipcode-search), worth to notice is that it only returns **first** match!

```
db.items.find({}, {items: {$elemMatch: {return: "admin"}}}});
```

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the aggregation framework, it is not the best solution though

```
db.collection.aggregate([
      {$unwind:'$items'},
      {$match:{'items.return':true}},
      {$group:{_id:'$_id', name: '$name',items:{$push:'$items'}}}
])
```